# Hi How to get child terms from a specific term and exclude some specific terms

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I am struggling to add 'exclude' to exclude some terms for the below code.
I cannot find the correct way to write such an array. Can anyone help me? Thanks

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'product_cat', 'parent=175' );
$count = count($terms);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<li><a href="'. get_term_link( $term ) .'">'. $term->name . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You can use the exclude key in the parameters. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your usage of `get_terms` is incorrect.
it takes an array of arguments like so:

```php
$terms = get_terms( array( 
 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
 'parent'   =>  $parent_id,
 'exclude'  =>  array( $ids, $to, $exclude )
 ) );
```